# Update Declare statements PtrSafe attribute for W64 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VB script that used to work on 32-bit VB. Now I've updated office to 64-bit, I get this error "Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute. Can anyone help?

```
  Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long


Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp\"

Sub download_image()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Image export")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ptrsafe-keyword

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm

Comment: Firstly, your code is not a VB script. VBScript does not use API. It is VBA. Secondly, do you have a URL in `ws.Range("B" & i).Value`? Then, you can easily find the correct declaration for 64 bit, following the links supplied above.

Comment: Thanks resolved it using 2 previous questions provided